# Java uses coma instead of dot for float

Tags: java, windows, types, number-formatting

I'm using a German version of Windows XP. Now I got a jar file from a project for test purposes. So far so good. The problem is that this jar file is converting data stored in the format in the English notation and it should stay in this. But the program is changing it form 50.4 to 50,4 and there is the problem that the software cannot work with this notation. On English OS versions it is working well. Does anyone how I can change this? I want that my Windows XP Java is using the English notation of the coma for numbers in floats and not the German notation.
Is it possible to change this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741658/how-do-i-change-the-default-locale-settings-in-java-to-make-them-consistent

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry that I didn't find the other post.